# ng-disabled on inputs from ng-repeat loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-disabled

I'm displaying inputs basing on array like this

```
 <div data-ng-repeat="n in langInput.values">
    <input type="text"
           id="auction_name_{{n.selected}}"
           class="form-control"
           name="auction_name_{{$index}}"
           data-ng-model="inputs.auction_name[$index + 1]"
           data-ng-minlength="5"
           data-ng-maxlength="60"
           required />
    <span data-ng-show="sellItem['auction_name_'+$index].$error.required">Wymagane!</span>
```

It also give's me ability of angularjs validation. Next after `<form>` is closed I want to create "next" button but I also want to do validation there so if user don't fullfill required inputs he will not be able to click it.

Array which I'm `ng-repeat`ing on is:

```
$scope.langInput = {
    count: 3,
    values: [
        {
            id: "1",
            selected: "pl"
        },
        {
            id: "2",
            selected: "eng"
        }
    ],
    add: function () {
        if (this.count < 7) {
            this.values.push({id: this.count, selected: "eng"});
            this.count += 1;
            console.log(this.values);
        }
    },
    remove: function () {
        if (this.count > 2) {
            this.values.pop();
            this.count -= 1;
            console.log(this.count);
        }
    }
};
```

I know I can use this `ng-disabled` directive however I don't know how I can check this inputs which are displayed in loop because its name is changing depending on `$index` of loop.

I've created [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/aJqQQkpuE6t5YGw3IOO5?p=preview)

---

My situation is that I know that I can disable button when some of element is invalid by `ng-disabled="sellItem.$error"` but in my form in real project I have this form much bigger and I have many ways of acomplishing form so in the end when user finish fullfilling form user still got some of inputs which are not even shown invalid.

So I can't use `ng-disabled="sellItem.$error"` because after user complete form he still got invalid inputs in background.

I also can not split form to many little forms because it will call 1 endpoint on submit.

What I did in real project is inject 3 different buttons and show them on correct step. Every of this button need to have ng-disabled to not let user to go to next step without completing step' inputs.

So intead of `ng-disabled="sellItem.$error"` I need to specify all inputs in ng-disabled of one step ( which is about 5 inputs ).

So it would look something like this:

```
ng-disabled="sellItem.first_input.$error && 
sellItem.second_input.$error && ..."
```

And I would do this but then I come to problem that I can't "loop" inside of `ng-disabled` and I want to "loop" inside it because names of inputs are generated by JS

```
name="auction_name_{{n.id}}"
```

they and not constant they change, user can add more inputs and delete them

at page start I have two inputs which after JS run are `name="auction_name_1"` and `name="auction_name_2"` (due to binding interpolated value) and then user can and third one `name="auction_name_3"`so I can't also hardcode them within `ng-disabled`.

Comment: presumably if you know the size of `langInput.values` you can ascertain which are available?

Comment: Yes but user can change count of inputs, he can add new and remove anyway I can ascertain somehow but I would need some additional function which would loop over inputs and set some flag if any of them is invalid

Comment: Where do you want to put that `ng-disabled` directive? I don't see a button in your code. Please show the whole code example, including the form and the buttons.

Comment: I tried but I'm clicking fork and it doesn't update my code at plnker. I want button below form

Comment: Now it's working https://plnkr.co/edit/aJqQQkpuE6t5YGw3IOO5?p=preview

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Maybe you want to use the [ng-required](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRequired) directive to  add the required validator to the ngModel directives.

Comment: I'll add edit  .

Comment: Question updated.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know how I can check this inputs which are displayed in loop because its name is changing depending on $index of loop.

Generally one stores the input as a property of the object in the array so that it stays with the object as its position in the array changes.

Also use the `id` property of the object:

```
<form name="sellItem" ng-submit="submit()">
    <div data-ng-repeat="n in langInput.values">
        <input type="text"
             id="auction_name_{{n.selected}}"
             class="form-control"
             ̶n̶a̶m̶e̶=̶"̶a̶u̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶_̶n̶a̶m̶e̶_̶{̶{̶$̶i̶n̶d̶e̶x̶}̶}̶"̶
             name="auction_name_{{n.id}}"
             ̶d̶a̶t̶a̶-̶n̶g̶-̶m̶o̶d̶e̶l̶=̶"̶i̶n̶p̶u̶t̶s̶.̶a̶u̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶_̶n̶a̶m̶e̶[̶$̶i̶n̶d̶e̶x̶ ̶+̶ ̶1̶]̶"̶
             data-ng-model="n.input"
             data-ng-minlength="5"
             data-ng-maxlength="60"
             required />
        <span data-ng-show="sellItem['auction_name_'+n.id].$error.required">Wymagane!</span>
        <span data-ng-show="sellItem['auction_name_'+n.id].$error.minlength">Za krótkie!</span>
        <span data-ng-show="sellItem['auction_name_'+n.id].$error.maxlength">Za długie!</span>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" ng-disabled="sellItem.$error">
          {{Submit}}
    </button>
</form>
```

Be sure to generate unique values for the `id` property.

---

### Update

Added <kbd>Submit</kbd> button.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - forms](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms)
- [AngularJS `<form>` Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form)
- [AngularJS ng-submit Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit)

Comment: but what inside ng-disabeld="here" ?

Comment: Please show also disabled button until every input is valid

Comment: Added `submit` button and `ng-submit` directive.

Comment: Yes I can achieve that like so in this demo but in my project I can't I need to specify exact input in `ng-disabled` because I have large form which contains many different path which has its own inputs. So not all inputs must be valid to disable this button. I have 3 different buttons and I can somehow disable them by reffering to single input like so `ng-disabled="sellItem.nameOfElement"` but I can't loop over inputs in ng-disabled